# jquery's mousenter-mouseleave for embeded image in button does not work on firefox and ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

The concept is when the mouse hovers on the button the image changes
It works perfectly on the chrome but it does not on firefox.

index.html

```
<button id="show_pdf1" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <img  id="img_btn1" src="lib/img/applet.png"
    width=" 240" height="160"></img>
</button>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img_btn1").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "lib/img/applet-hover.png");
    })
    $("#img_btn1").mouseleave(function () {
         $(this).attr("src", "lib/img/applet.png");
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7vex2cu/4/

Any ideas why?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event to the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#show_pdf1").mouseenter(function () {
       $("#img_btn1").attr("src", "lib/img/applet-hover.png");
   }).mouseleave(function () {
     $("#img_btn1").attr("src", "lib/img/applet.png");
   })
})
```

Updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7vex2cu/6/)